# The character of the textarea input is turned to object

Tags: html

for example
       in 
       input  name:1111,ss:1111,...   => {name:1111,ss:1111,...}
       A method of turning characters into objects

```
   I can't find a good way to do it
```

Comment: The operation you're talking about is called String Parsing and it cannot be accomplished with html alone. What's your final goal?

Comment: Characters turn to objects

Comment: I think you're looking for this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/1187199

Comment: Do you want to parse the input of yout field and get the javascript object of it ?

Comment: You need to specify what programming language you want to use to do this. HTML is not a programming language so it can't do it alone.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need this method or what?

if need method, it's simple: just get value of `textarea`, wrap text into quotes, add braces and call on it `JSON.parse()`

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("id-of-textarea");
var value = textarea.value;
var wrapped = "{"+value.replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"') + "}";
var result = JSON.parse(wrapped);
```

But, you should expect any values that user can input, so it's not good idea to use textarea for input some data.

Comment: I was thinking the same using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

As per the structure of you input I would suggest you to use different textfields to capture data rather than having it into a single textarea. Like this, you will be able to iterate over those and fetch their value and store them in form of an object or a map

**Your HTML:**

```
<input id="name" value="1111"/>
<input id="ss" value="2222"/>
...
```

**Your script (JQuery/Javascript):**

```
var data = {};
$('input').each(function () {

data[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();

});
```